# How do I check if SqlCacheDependency is enabled at runtime?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, caching, web-config, sqlcachedependency

I am using SqlCacheDependency with polling in an ASP.NET project.

Sometimes, I need to disable SqlCacheDependency, which I do as follows:

```
<caching>
  <sqlCacheDependency enabled="false" pollTime="10000">
    <databases>
      <!-- ... -->
    </databases>
  </sqlCacheDependency>
</caching>
```

However, this causes an error in my code when I do a HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert() with the SQL dependency.

*To enable SQL cache dependency, please set the 'enabled' attribute to "true" in the  section in the configuration file.*

Is there a way I can programmatically check if this setting is enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code worked for me...

```
//using System.Web.Configuration;
Configuration webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
string configPath = "system.web/caching/sqlCacheDependency";
SqlCacheDependencySection section = (SqlCacheDependencySection)webConfig.GetSection(configPath);
bool enabled = section.Enabled;
```